# VBA Excel Copy Range from a already autofiltered Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet containing data. As soon as something changes in a specific column, I want to copy the values of one column in this sheet to another worksheet, but only rows which match some criteria. So I have auto-filtered a range. This works. It only returns rows matching the filter. But from this filtered range, I only need one column. Somehow I cannot get this to work.

So my question would be, how can I only copy a specific column from a filtered range?

Code (snipped) I have so far:

```
Me.AutoFilterMode = False
With Me.Range("C4:D103")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Marge Only", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Contracting"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Range("B5:B104")
End With

ThisWorkbook.SortResult

On Error Resume Next
    Me.AutoFilterMode = False
    Me.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

The .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy part copies too much data to the destination worksheet. I need something like:

```
.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

With .Range("A:A") my thought would be that only column A from the already filtered range would be copied. But this doesn't work.

So what would be your advice how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code slightly to copy only the column you need. This code assumes column A (but you can adjust) and it assumes row 4 is header data (you can also adjust.

```
With Me
    .Range("C4:D103").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=Marge Only", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Contracting"
    .Range("A5:A103").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Range("B5")
End With
```

Comment: Scott, that did it. I think good to mention. Column A refers to the filtered range (Range("C4:D103"), so column A is C in the original range). This works perfectly for me. @DaBeau96. Thanks for answering too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are talking about? It checks column "I" for the criterial then it finds the first and last cells in a filter "A" column and copies the values between the two and paste it in column "O"

```
Sub copyColumn()
Dim StrRow As Long
Dim str As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
 With Sheet1
  .AutoFilterMode = False
   With .Range("A1:M1")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="dog"
    StrRow = Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Row
    str = .Range("A" & StrRow).Address
    str2 = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address
    .Range("O2:O" & str3).Value = .Range(str, str2).Value
    End With
    End With
End Sub
```